# Identifying syslog files, also does auth.log mirror what is in /vars/syslog?

Tags: log, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I am writing a auth log parser as a means to contribute to a tool and to learn linux logging better.  I have been reading up on syslog and log facilities and was wondering if what is in auth.log will also be duplicated in syslog.log?  Does it just make sense to only parse syslog and not other facility specific log files, assuming I want as much as I can get anyways? I guess what I am asking is there ever a time that there will be a unique log instance found in auth.log that will not also be included in syslog?

in addition, when looking at a log file such as auth.log. is there a sure way of telling what facility is being used other just the log name and path. Just thinking of terms of log identification when dealing with moved, renamed or deleted log files.

Comment: This seems like two separate questions, which might be why some people have voted to close it as *too broad*. I recommend removing the second part of this question and posting it as a new, separate question--or, if you feel sure it should be considered an inseparable part of the first question, then edit to make clear the connection. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Read `man rsyslog.conf`, and inspect `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`. In `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` you will see:

```
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

which shows that `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/syslog` do NOT get the same messages.